# how to store the returnvariable from cffuction in coldfusion and to do data validation

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am using `cfinvoke` component to return two query objects. I am able to get the results from my queries with the help of the `returnvariable` attribute. I have confirmed the results using `cfdump`. Now I need to do a data validation of the data inside the two return variables.

```
<cfinvoke component="Db_processing" 
    method="TimesheetMain" returnvariable="tsdata">
</cfinvoke>

<cfinvoke component="Db_processing" method="MstMain"
     returnvariable="mstdata">
</cfinvoke>
```

I don't know how to store all the returntype values or how to parse through them in order to compare the values inside two returnvariables.

COMPARISON SCENARIO example:
Fetch date and hours from returnvariable[tsdata] and returnvariable[mstdata] and compare them. If it fails, then I need to drop a mail to a certain user.

I need to do many validations like this. Can any one help me in this?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please post 1) a sample of the data in the two queries AND 2) a brief explanation what you are trying to compare and 3) the desired result .   Also, what database are you using (sql server, mysql, ....)?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear but it looks like that you have two query result sets stored in two variables and you want to compare these two within coldfusion application. If my assumption is correct then read through:

Do a nested loop for query - Do a loop using first resultset and for the datetime column (say tsdata) match against every msdata row of second result set.

If this is not what you were expecting then explain your question more.